# magnet torrent by private server

Tags: bittorrent

1.I have a web server like torrent.server.com

2.The server can make a torrent for the upload file.

3.I can publish the torrent download link on the download page.

Now I want to generate a magnet link for the torrent.I have read the information on the wiki about magnet bit torrent.And when I copy the magnet link to BTclient like BitComet I found that the client can not find or download the .torrent file.

Here is the magnet link example:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:815909a9e9a7e05f294eed9ab274a94235cea301
```

I think there is no information about this torrent on the Internet so BTclient can not find the torrent?

Comment: There must be at least one peer that already seed the torrent for this to work. Also, if the 'private' flag was set when the torrent was created, magnet links won't work, because then **metadata transfer**, **DHT**, PEX and LPD will be disabled.

Comment: do I need to build a server to seed every torrent once?

Comment: that does not seem to be related to magnets. to get magnets to work it is necessary that both parties can speak to each other and understand the protocols that @Encombe mentioned.